# Raised exception seemingly not caught

Tags: python, python-3.x

I run an application with `futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)`. On linux, it runs fine. On two different macos, it freezes/locks/we don't know. When we hit CTRL+C on the macoss, the following stack trace is printed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/parallel/recorder_tool.py", line 168, in __enter__
  File "tests/parallel/recorder_tool.py", line 168, in __enter__
  File "tests/parallel/recorder_tool.py", line 168, in __enter__
  File "tests/parallel/recorder_tool.py", line 168, in __enter__
    self.manager = self.__class__.managers.pop()
    self.manager = self.__class__.managers.pop()
    self.manager = self.__class__.managers.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
IndexError: pop from empty list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    self.manager = self.__class__.managers.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyboardInterrupt

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyboardInterrupt
IndexError: pop from empty list
KeyboardInterrupt
Exception ignored in: 'grpc._cython.cygrpc._next'
...
```

Here is the code sample related to the `IndexError`.

```
try:                                            
    self.manager = self.__class__.managers.pop()
except IndexError:                              
    self.manager = Factory.get_manager(get_conn)
```

There is an `except IndexError` block, but the stack trace makes it look like it's never reached. Is there something really fishy that I should investigate here or is it simply because Ctrl+C was pressed so no more exception handler work? Also, is there any obvious reason why it would work on linux and not on macos?

Thanks!

Comment: How is `managers` defined?  What does `Factory.get_manager` do?  It sounds like you have a loop where you continually try to `pop` the same empty list

Comment: Each process in the process pool tries to pop from the empty list indeed. That's on purpose and I have the `except IndexError` to handle that, but it doesn't seem to work. I can add more code if needed but I felt like it would be superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IndexError is being caught. Untangling the interleaved stack traces, it appears that the KeyboardInterrupt arrived (in each process) while the IndexError was being handled. The following line:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

indicates [implicit exception chaining](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/#implicit-exception-chaining). A new exception occurred while an existing exception was being handled, so the two exceptions were attached together, and both stack traces were printed.

Comment: I suspected something like that. Thank you for the confirmation.